# Numbered reference writing style: Breakable space or not?

Tags: cross-referencing, line-breaking, typography

Should a list of numbered reference be displayed with non-breakable spaces ? If I have only one, the obvious rule is to use "~", e.g. `Lemma~\ref{fundamental}`.

But if I want to say "By Lemma 1, 2 and 3 it follows that ...", do I use `By Lemma~\ref{fundamental}, \ref{goldbach} and \ref{riemann} it follows that ...` or `By Lemma~\ref{fundamental},~\ref{goldbach} and~\ref{riemann} it follows that ...` ?
(The difference consists of the additional `~`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend -- note the plural form of "Lemma" (choose either "Lemmas" or "Lemmata"):

```
By Lemmas~\ref{fundamental}, \ref{goldbach} and~\ref{riemann} it follows that ...
```

Even better, load the `cleveref` package and write

```
By \cref{fundamental,,goldbach,riemann} it follows that ...
```

and let LaTeX generate

> By Lemmas 1, 2 and 3 it follows that ...

There will be an unbreakable space before "1" and "3", but not before "2".

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm, xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev, nameinlink, capitalize]{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}[Fundamental] \label{lem:fund} abc \end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}[Goldbach] \label{lem:gold} def \end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}[Riemann]  \label{lem:riem} ghi \end{lemma}

By \cref{lem:fund,,lem:gold,lem:riem} it follows that ...

\end{document}
```